# Mojave command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, macos, tesseract, macos-mojave

I've been looking for an answer to this issue but I couldn't find it, so here it is.
I'm trying to install tesserocr into MacOS X Mojave (Python 3.6) using:

```
$ pip install tesserocr
```

Then I get the following error:

```
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall 
-Wstrict-prototypes -I/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/4.0.0/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/leptonica/1.77.0/include 
-I/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c tesserocr.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-
x86_64-3.6/tesserocr.o -std=c++11 -DUSE_STD_NAMESPACE


warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-std=libc++' on the command line
to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]

tesserocr.cpp:580:10: fatal error: 'utility' file not found

#include <utility>

1 warning and 1 error generated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1


Failed building wheel for tesserocr
```

P.s. I have installed the latest version of Xcode and Xcode CLI.

Thanks.